# Function changing its sign passing through a point

Tags: calculus

What does it mean to say that a function changes its sign passing through a particular point?

Can we say that a function $f(x)$ changes its sign from positive to negative passing through a point $x=a$ if there exists a $\delta$ such that whenever $$a-\delta <x \leq a,  f(x) \geq 0$$ and whenever $$a \leq x <a+\delta, f(x) \leq 0$$

Comment: I'd replace $\le$ with $<$ throughout.

Comment: Here, $f$ is chanding from positive to negative, but it could also be the other way round!

Answer (score 0):

If the function is continuous then the function must have a root there. So $f(a)=0$.

Comment: Is the fact written above correct?

Comment: @user679770 It is. (Bolzano's theorem) Unfortunatelly, this condition is necessary rather than sufficient

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this:

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. We say that $f$ changes sign at the point $z \in (a,b)$ if $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in (z-\delta, z), \forall y \in (z, z+\delta)$, we have $f(x)f(y)<0$

This way we consider both cases (negative-to-positive or positive-to-negative) simultaneously. The definition I posted prior to editting was wrong, as it included cases where $f$ changed sign infinitely many times close to $z$, but always on the same side

Answer (score 0):

Your condition seems correct. There must be a neighborhood of the point such that the sign is constant and different on either sides. The function needn't be continuous (nowhere).

More precisely and in the widest sense, the must exist a neighborhood of $a$ such that $f$ is non-negative but not identically zero on the left and non-positive but not identically zero on the right (or conversely).